# Load page in CefSharp before it has focus

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, cefsharp

TL;DR - Is there any way to get pages to load in CefSharp before the control gets focus?  Even though I've supplied the URL it will only start loading when the control gets focus.

Full version:

I have a WPF application which has a Tabcontrol with five tabs and in two of those tabs I want to load two web pages that are used frequently as part of using the app.  Both of these sites load their respective login page and then I have Javascript commands to do the login via ExecuteJavaScriptAsync().

To do all this I created a Usercontrol hosting the ChromiumWebBrowser control and it all works perfectly *except* that the pages will only load when I actually click on each of the web browser tabs - in other words, it seems the loading will only happen when it gets explicit focus.

What I need is for CefSharp to just load the pages in the background so that when the user does need to go to the web page tabs the sites are already loaded and the user is logged in.

Previously I was using GeckoBrowser and that loads the pages in the background as I need but I can't use that control anymore as it has an uncatchable internal error that keeps crashing my app.  I also can't use the WebView or older WebControl as I am unable to get the Javascript commands to log in to each site to work.

I've added XAML and code below (though I don't think they are really necessary) but my question is really simple - how can I get pages to load in CefSharp before the control gets focus?

Here are my tabs in my MainWindow.xaml...

```
<TabItem>

    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Rebrickable" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </TabItem.Header>

    <Grid Name="grdRebrickable" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>

<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="BrickLink" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </TabItem.Header>

    <Grid Name="grdBrickLink" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

...and in code behind I have this which is called when the MainWindow starts:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      //Instantiate our browser controls, add them to each of the tab items and load their home pages.
      PrepareBrowserControls();
}

private void PrepareBrowserControls()
{
    csBrickLink = new CefSharpBrowser(BrowserType.BrickLink, AppGlobals.BrickLinkBaseURL);
    grdBrickLink.Children.Add(csBrickLink);
    csBrickLink.LoadURL(AppGlobals.BrickLinkBaseURL);

    csRebrickable = new CefSharpBrowser(BrowserType.Rebrickable, AppGlobals.RebrickableBaseURL);
    grdRebrickable.Children.Add(csRebrickable);
    csRebrickable.LoadURL(AppGlobals.RebrickableBaseURL);
}
```

XAML for CefSharpBrowser UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MOCManager.Controls.CefSharpBrowser"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
   xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MOCManager.Controls"
   mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <!-- other XAML here left out for brevity -->

        <cef:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="cefBrowser"    
             FrameLoadEnd="cefBrowser_FrameLoadEnd" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And core code for UserControl (some left out for brevity):

```
    public partial class CefSharpBrowser : UserControl
    {
        //enumeration of site types to load
        private BrowserType _browserType;

        //Login page URL of the sire to load    
        private string _baseURL;

        public CefSharpBrowser(BrowserType browserType, string baseUrl)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this._browserType = browserType;
            this._baseURL = baseUrl;
        }

        public void LoadURL(string url)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) && url.ToLower().StartsWith("http"))
                cefBrowser.Address = url;
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid or missing URL!");
        }

       private void cefBrowser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
       {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate
                {
                    txtURL.Text = e.Url;
                    txtStatus.Text = "Page loaded";
                }));

                //Do automated logins depending on the site 
                if (e.Url.Contains("login/?next="))
                {
                    SetStatus("Logging into Rebrickable...");

                    cefBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('input[name=username]').val(\"joebloggs\")");
                    cefBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('input[name=password]').val(\"abc123\")");
                    cefBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('button[type=\"submit\"]').click();");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (e.Url.Contains("login.page"))
                    {
                        SetStatus("Logging into BrickLink...");

                        cefBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('input[name=frmUsername]').val(\"joebloggs\")");
                        cefBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('input[name=frmPassword]').val(\"abc123\")");
                        cefBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('input[name=frmStayLoggedIn]').checked=true");
                        cefBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("$('button[type=\"submit\"]').click();");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: I solved this for now by simply selecting the 2 tabs with the CefSharp instances by doing tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = x after calling LoadURL on my UserControl... not ideal but the pages in the browser controls do at least load.  However, I'd still like to know if I can get pages to start loading without having to do this nasty hack.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/initialization-for-object-elements-not-in-an-object-tree